# Markdown with GeSHi Usage

Tags: php, markdown, geshi, smartypants

I was using Markdown for a while for formatting rich contents. Then I needed a bit extra, something like how our StackOverflow does. So, I thought of getting GeSHi work with Markdown.

I tried that `markdown_extra_geshi`, but I couldn't work on it. At that moment, I saw a project [**Beautify**](http://www.bitstorm.org/weblog/2012-8/Beautify_Markdown_SmartyPants_GeSHi_and_Dot_combined.html) ([GitHub](https://github.com/edwinm/Beautify)).

Markdown works fine, but a few issues. Syntax Highlighting is not working. SmartyPants is converting the quotes inside the code too.

The Markdown Snippet which I gave as input was:

```
#Checking Codes!
The `inline code` and **big code**:

    {{lang:php}}
    echo "string";

###Same way!

    #!php
    echo "string";
```

I got the HTML output as:

```
<h1>Checking Codes!</h1>

<p>The <code>inline code</code> and <strong>big code</strong>:</p>

<pre><code>{{lang:php}}
echo &amp;#8220;string&amp;#8221;;
</code></pre>

<h3>Same way!</h3>

<pre><code>#!php
echo &amp;#8220;string&amp;#8221;;
</code></pre>
```

Actually it shouldn't have converted the quotes into smart quotes and I couldn't find the Syntax Highlighting. Am I doing it wrong? The source code of this test file is:

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    include("beautify.php");
    echo beautify('#Checking Codes!
The `inline code` and **big code**:

    {{lang:php}}
    echo "string";

###Same way!

    #!php
    echo "string";
');
?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please refrain from **random** bold **formatting**, it makes your question harder to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got the answer from the author himself.

You should put your code between `~~~`.

Like this:

```
~~~ php
echo "here's PHP code";
~~~
Here's normal text.
```

Future visitors might get help from this. :)